# configuring app.yaml for Google AppEngine to serve ajax requests for PHP

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine

I've a simple folder structure,

```
main
 |__core
      |__start.php
      |__bootstrap.php
js
 |__file.js

css
 |__file.css

index.php
```

Now, this `file.js` makes `xhr request` to `start.php` for which I'm getting a 500 error.

This is my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css
```

Now I'm not sure if I'm also suppose to do this:

```
- url: /main/core/.*
  script: start.php
```

Which, by the way, doesn't seem entirely legit to me.

Comment: Can you show the full error, including the requested path?

Comment: the status code just says 500. and the http request path is `/main/core/start.php`

Comment: What about the app log?

Comment: thank you very much, forgot to check the logs. turns out curl wasn't enabled, so I created a php.ini in the root dir and added this line `extension = "curl.so"`

Comment: it's all working fine now. thanks for your time